# duplicate POST, GET and DELETE request using backbone js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, duplicates, crud, restful-url

I have a simle CRUD application. But when i do delete , create or edit Nth time N number of request get fired.

For example If i am creating a user  3rd time the 3 POST request gets fired.

when i refresh the page only one request is fired. Please help. below is my code.

HTML

```
     <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>My App</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>


      <div class="container">
        <h1>User Manager</h1>
        <hr />
        <div class="page"> </div>

      </div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 <script src="http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
 function htmlEncode(value){
      return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
    }
 </script>
<script type="text/template" id="user-list-template">
    <a href="#/new" class="btn btn-primary">New</a>
    <hr />
    <table class="table striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Age</th><th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= htmlEncode(user.get('firstname')) %></td>
            <td><%= htmlEncode(user.get('lastname')) %></td>
            <td><%= htmlEncode(user.get('age')) %></td>
            <td><a class="btn" href="#/edit/<%= user.id %>">Edit</a></td>
          </tr>
        <% }); %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>

  <script type="text/template" id="edit-user-template">
    <form class="edit-user-form">
      <legend><%= user ? 'Edit' : 'New' %> User</legend>
        <label>First Name</label>
        <input name="firstname" type="text" value="<%= user ? user.get('firstname') : '' %>">
        <label>Last Name</label>
        <input name="lastname" type="text" value="<%= user ? user.get('lastname') : '' %>">
        <label>Age</label>
        <input name="age" type="text" value="<%= user ? user.get('age') : '' %>">
        <hr />
       <button type="submit" class="btn"><%= user ? 'Update' : 'Create' %></button>
       <% if(user) { %>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= user.id %>" />
       <button data-user-id="<%= user.id %>" class="btn btn-danger delete">Delete</button>
       <% }; %>
    </form>
  </script>
 <script src="user.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var Myapp ={};
$.ajaxPrefilter( function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
      options.url = 'http://backbonejs-beginner.herokuapp.com' + options.url;
    });
// Setting up user collection
  Myapp.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      url: '/users'
 });
// setting up user model
  Myapp.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
     urlRoot: '/users',
     validate: function(attrs, options) {
            if (attrs.firstname =='') {
              alert("First Name cannot be blank.");
              return "First Name cannot be blank.";
            }
        }
 });


 // setting up routes
   Myapp.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          "": "home", 
          "edit/:id": "edit",
          "new": "edit",
        }
    });

   Myapp.router = new Myapp.Router;
     Myapp.router.on('route:home', function() {
          // render user list
          Myapp.displayUsersModule.init().render();
        })
        Myapp.router.on('route:edit', function(id) {
          Myapp.editUserViewModule.init().render({id: id});
        })

// display user module imkplemented in module patern. The only public api is the init function      
 Myapp.displayUsersModule = (function(){
    var UserListView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '.page',
        render: function () {
        var that = this;
        var users = new Myapp.Users();
        users.fetch({
          success: function (users) {
            var template = _.template($('#user-list-template').html(), {users: users.models});
            that.$el.html(template);
          },
          error: function (model, xhr, options) {
            alert("Something went wrong while fetching details");
            }
        })
      }
    });

  var init = function() {
        userListView =  new UserListView();
        return userListView;
  };

  return {
        init: init
    };


})();
// edit and delete user module imkplemented in module patern. The only public api is the init function  
 Myapp.editUserViewModule = (function(){

    var UserEditView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '.page',
      events: {
        'submit .edit-user-form': 'saveUser',
        'click .delete': 'deleteUser'
      },
      saveUser: function (ev) {
        var userDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
        var user = new Myapp.User();
        user.save(userDetails, {
          success: function (user) {
            Myapp.router.navigate('', {trigger:true});
          },
           error: function (model, xhr, options) {
            alert("Something went wrong while saving details");
            }
        });
        return false;
      },
      deleteUser: function (ev) {
        alert(1);
        this.user.destroy({
          success: function () {
            console.log('destroyed');
            Myapp.router.navigate('', {trigger:true});
          },
           error: function (model, xhr, options) {
            alert("Something went wrong while Deleting user");
            }
        });

        return false;
      },
      render: function (options) {
        var that = this;
        if(options.id) {
          that.user = new Myapp.User({id: options.id});
          that.user.fetch({
            success: function (user) {    
              var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {user: user});
              that.$el.html(template);
            }
          })
        } else {
          var template = _.template($('#edit-user-template').html(), {user: null});
          that.$el.html(template);
        }

      }
    });

    var init = function() {
            var userEditView = new UserEditView();      
            return userEditView;
  };

  return {
        init: init
    };



})();


$(document).ready(function(){

  $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
      var o = {};
      var a = this.serializeArray();
      $.each(a, function() {
          if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
              if (!o[this.name].push) {
                  o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
              }
              o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
          } else {
              o[this.name] = this.value || '';
          }
      });
      return o;
    };

    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't correct unbind views when switching them, so you have multiple zombie view that listen to the same DOM events (it is because you attach them to DOM using `el: 'selector'` style that is not pretty good).

To fix it you should call [remove](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) (or `undelegateEvents`) method when you don't need it anymore.

Or you can use libraries that help you to manage views such as:

- [backbone.layoutmanager](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager)
- [backbone.marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette)